# Where does the colon (:) belong in the Apex SOQL query - to the operator or the variable?

Tags: apex, bestpractice, naming-convention

I'm asking about a best practice - Salesforce gives us freedom here but we'd like to establish some sort of consistency in our team. Similar to the case size - although Apex is case-insensitive, it's recommended to write it with having camelCase in mind for variables/methods and PascalCase for classes.

So in Apex code that uses an SOQL query with a variable as a filter, where should the colon belong - to the operator or the variable?

`[SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = :variable]`

or

`[SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name =: variable]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`:` is the binding operator. It behaves differently depending on if you're using inline SOQL/SOSL or dynamic SOQL/SOSL.

With inline queries, `:` starts a section of Apex Code execution within the query. It may or may not have white space on either side. The following three queries are identical:

```
SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = :accountName
SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = : accountName
SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name =:accountName
```

Since `:` can be code, you can even:

```
SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = :getAccountName()
```

In Dynamic SOQL/SOSL, the rules are different. The `:` cannot have a space after it, and what follows must be a variable name, not any kind of Apex Code.

Valid:

```
SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = :accountName
```

Invalid:

```
SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = : accountName
SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = :getAccountName()
SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = :accountNames[0]
SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = :accountsVar.someProp
```

As far as which side should "own" the colon, it must be the variable. This provides a consistent reading experience, especially when you start using dynamic queries, as it is already required.

Most developers also strongly prefer that operators have spaces on either side, so `=` "owns" the space on either side of it, which is why we wouldn't ordinarily write `Name=:accountName`. The `:` has nothing to do with this formatting style, it's the operator that demands some space.

Answer (score 5):

From a practical standpoint, either works. While SOQL does have *some* syntactically significant whitespace (e.g. between filters in the WHERE clause, between the last field in the SELECT clause and the start of the FROM clause), it doesn't matter here. Even `Name=:variable` would work.

Personally, I prefer the `Name = :variable` approach, because the piece in the middle of that expression is an *operator*, and `=:`, `<:`, `>=:`, etc... aren't SOQL/SOSL operators.

Answer (score 2):

To the variable, because it is not part of the operator.

And I like to consider it as some sort of modifier/pointer to make that variable work with the query.